# grid dip AN/PRM10: Is the normal operating distance so small?

Tags: ham-radio

I recently bought an AN/PRM-10 multifunction grid dip. After I replaced some electron tubes by new ones, most of the functions seem to work fine, but in the grid dip mode, I get no dip unless I place the coil very near to the resonant circuit to be tested (no more than 2-3 cm). My question for all the persons who are used with grid dips: is it the normal operating distance ? I thought the circuit would react even at 20 cm at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close coupling is normal, especially when scanning frequency for resonance. Orientation is important too - in the first photo, two coils are tightly coupled. In the second photo, two coils are very loosely-coupled  If one coil was your grid-dip meter's search coil, it would give a poor dip indication.[image: tightly coupled coils][image: loose coupled coils]
However, once the resonant dip has been found, move the grid-dip meter's search coil further away to see the slight dip - then record the resonant frequency (this frequency will be most accurate).
Probing coils wound on closed-path ferrite material (like toroids) is difficult, and requires especially-close coupling.

Comment: If the coil under test is an air core coil (like one of the coils of the grid dip itself, wired with a suitable capacitor), at approximately what distance should the meter cease to dip ? (I just want to know if my grid dip works fine).

Comment: @MikeTeX That's a good point - a high-Q resonator yields a sharp dip perhaps 10 cm away. A low-Q resonator gives a broad dip that requires closer coupling. (Air-coils are often high-Q). To start, probe a resonator considerably closer than 10 cm until you find resonance.